# Is Guzzle prepending lines to my downloaded text/csv file?

Tags: php, laravel, csv, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle. I am trying to download various .csv files from USGS (http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php).

Sometimes, the downloaded file content is prefixed with some extra bytes followed by a "\r\n". In other words, sometimes, a line is prefixed to the file content.

Example: 0000AFEB\r\n

It looks to me like the server does not return this content, so perhaps it's added by PHP/Guzzle?

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to find out what the hell this is? :D

Below I have pasted some output from a terminal to demonstrate the issue.

I believe this is the raw output from the HTTP server at USGS

```
me@localhost:~/Desktop$ curl -s http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.csv | hexdump -c -n 50
0000000   t   i   m   e   ,   l   a   t   i   t   u   d   e   ,   l   o
0000010   n   g   i   t   u   d   e   ,   d   e   p   t   h   ,   m   a
0000020   g   ,   m   a   g   T   y   p   e   ,   n   s   t   ,   g   a
0000030   p   ,                                                        
0000032
```

This is an interactive Laravel console which downloads the same file as the curl command above (but using Guzzle). This seems to work as expected...

```
me@localhost:~/Desktop$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
=> GuzzleHttp\Client {#680}

>>> $url = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.csv';
=> "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.csv"

>>> $result = $client->request('GET', $url, ['save_to' => '/tmp/all_hour.csv']);
=> GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#708}

# Dump the first 200 characters of the downloaded file
>>> dd(substr(file_get_contents('/tmp/all_hour.csv'), 0, 200));
"""
time,latitude,longitude,depth,mag,magType,nst,gap,dmin,rms,net,id,updated,place,type,horizontalError,depthError,magError,magNst,status,locationSource,magSource\n
2016-08-26T08:21:47.530Z,33.8725,-116.94
"""
```

Try the same on another (larger) .csv file. Check the raw output, looks ok...

```
me@localhost:~/Desktop$ curl -s http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.csv | hexdump -c -n 50
0000000   t   i   m   e   ,   l   a   t   i   t   u   d   e   ,   l   o
0000010   n   g   i   t   u   d   e   ,   d   e   p   t   h   ,   m   a
0000020   g   ,   m   a   g   T   y   p   e   ,   n   s   t   ,   g   a
0000030   p   ,                                                        
0000032
```

Try another Laravel session to download the same file using Guzzle. This example shows that the downloaded file content has had a new line prepended (the string "0000AFEB\r\n"). What is this? Why is it there?

```
me@localhost:~/Desktop$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 — cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
=> GuzzleHttp\Client {#680}

>>> $url = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.csv';
=> "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.csv"

>>> $result = $client->request('GET', $url, ['save_to' => '/tmp/all_day.csv']);
=> GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#708}

>>> dd(substr(file_get_contents('/tmp/all_day.csv'), 0, 200));
"""
0000AFEB\r\n
time,latitude,longitude,depth,mag,magType,nst,gap,dmin,rms,net,id,updated,place,type,horizontalError,depthError,magError,magNst,status,locationSource,magSource\n
2016-08-26T08:29:05.500Z,33.49
"""
```

A few suffixed lines are also added when this happens, for example.

```
\n
00000000\n
\n
```

I'm sure there's a sensible answer/reason for this behavior... but I really can't find it!

Here is the server headers that are output for the two files used above...

```
me@localhost:~/Desktop$ curl -I http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.csv
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.35
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Aug 2016 08:33:01 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept,origin,authorization,content-type
Content-Type: text/csv
Cache-Control: public, max-age=277
Expires: Fri, 26 Aug 2016 08:41:50 GMT
Date: Fri, 26 Aug 2016 08:37:13 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

me@localhost:~/Desktop$ curl -I http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.csv
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.35
Last-Modified: Fri, 26 Aug 2016 08:32:32 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept,origin,authorization,content-type
Content-Type: text/csv
Cache-Control: public, max-age=90
Expires: Fri, 26 Aug 2016 08:38:59 GMT
Date: Fri, 26 Aug 2016 08:37:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```